# Exception: Layout must be a dash component or a function that returns a dash component

Tags: python-3.x, dashboard, web-frameworks, plotly-dash

I am trying this simple piece of code and it is rising an exception mentioned in the title.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel("https://github.com/chris1610/pbpython/
blob/master/data/salesfunnel.xlsx?raw=True")

pv = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Name'], columns=["Status"], values= 
['Quantity'], aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)

trace1 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Quantity', 'declined')], name='Declined')
trace2 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Quantity', 'pending')], name='Pending')
trace3 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Quantity', 'presented')], name='Presented')
trace4 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Quantity', 'won')], name='Won')

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
html.H1(children='Sales Funnel Report'),
html.Div(children='''National Sales Funnel Report.'''),
dcc.Graph(
    id='example-graph',
    figure={
        'data': [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4],
        'layout':
        go.Layout(title='Order Status by Customer', barmode='stack')
    })
])
```

So, It points to the last line of the program i.e go.Layout and mentions this error.
I had tried quite a few things and I dint find the reason for this error. Would be great help if anyone could resolve this issue.
Thanking in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce this Exception. Id did have to change two things in the given code.

1) The stray line break in the `read_excel` line (probably an artifact of code copying)

2) Adding the following to actually run the app:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

These might be very trivial, and your problem might be something completely different, but after these two changes the app ran smoothly for me.